# Jasmine tests that require outside libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jasmine

I was wondering what is best practice or at least a practice for using Jasmine to test javascript that requires **remote** libraries called on page load, but not in the app.

More specifically, I'm creating a backbone view for processing payments using stripe.  Stripe recommends that you load their javascript in your layout from their servers.

But my tests don't have my layout, so when I try to do this

```
it("calls stripe token creation", function() {
  stripeSpy = spyOn(Stripe, "createToken");
  form.submit();
  expect(stripeSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

It gives the error.

```
Stripe is not defined
```

I'd rather not depend on remote libraries for my test, nor do I really want to go against stripe preferred method of relying on their source code. What would be the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To mock out the `Stripe` dependency you have to create a new `Stripe` object with the function you want to call:

```
var Stripe = {createToken: sinon.spy()} 
form.submit();
expect(Stripe.createToken).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Sinon.JS to mock\stub this out.

Check out http://sinonjs.org/

Example usage for jQuery's AJAX stub

```
it("makes a GET request for todo items", function () {
    sinon.stub(jQuery, "ajax");
    getTodos(42, sinon.spy());

    assert(jQuery.ajax.calledWithMatch({ url: "/todo/42/items" }));
});
```

For yours I'd imagine you'd do something like `sinon.stub(Stripe, "createToken")`

Hope this helps.